# Converting tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter to tensorflow datasets

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to develop an image classification model using CNN on my own image dataset
I am aware of developing such models with existing datasets in tensorflow
But I am struggling to add my dataset to tensorflow
I has already tried to convert prepare an image dataset using the below code and type(dataset) is tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter
Now, I want to add this to tensorflow datasets, such that I can load the dataset easily using dataset.load_data()

Can anyone help me?

In the file.csv, Image column contains the Image names and Class column contains the class of the image
I am passing these columns as parameters to tf.constant() as shown in below code.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

filenames = tf.constant(df.Image)
labels = tf.constant(df.Class)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))

def _parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
   return image, label

dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset = dataset.batch(2)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
images, labels = iterator.get_next()
```

Comment: You can pass a TF Dataset to the fit method, e.g.

`fit(dataset, ...other params here...)`

and TF will extract batches from the Dataset object as needed.